# Очистка буфера обмена при Tk.destroy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, clipboard

В `буфер обмена добавляется 'ABC'`, далее два варианта развития событий:

- `Ждать` до закрытия программы, в итоге в буфер обмена будет `пустой`.
- Если же `за 3000 мсек`, содержимое буфера обмена, `вставить`, например в блокнот, буфер `не очищается` и после завершения программы.

Почему так?

```
import tkinter

Tk = tkinter.Tk()
Tk.withdraw()
Tk.clipboard_clear()
Tk.clipboard_append('ABC')
Tk.update()

Tk.after(3000, Tk.destroy)
# тут буфер надо вставить в блокнот
Tk.mainloop()
# иначе тут буфер будет пустой
```

Comment: А у меня не получается воспроизвести под debian/openbox описанное поведение ни вашего кода, ни [аналога на TCL](https://pastebin.com/DZKg2wQ5), буфер очищается при завершении программы, даже если успеваешь куда-то вставить содержимое.

Comment: у меня воспроизводится на windows 10

Comment: @AlexanderZonov: я ошибся. При более внимательном рассмотрении поведение у меня также не воспроизводится (просто редактор, который я использовал, сам запоминал вставленный текст -- в других программах содержимое буфера обмена всегда пропадает на Ubuntu, когда скрипт заканчивается, как описано в https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence . Что можно исправить установив clipboard manager: `$ sudo apt install parcellite` (после reboot).